# Show git branch in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project folder structure like this : `Code/Repo/<repo_folder_name>/..subfolders` and in the `<repo_folder_name>` i have the hidden `.git` folder because i cloned from Sourcetree to this folder .

Eclipse does show the current branch , but when i open this folder in Visual Studio Code , i know it must show the current branch name , in the bottom left side .

Does anybody know how to do this ? To show the branch name in Visual Studio Code ?

Thank you very much.

-- > I added Sourcetree`s bin folder to the PATH and now everything is working ok :D . Sourcetree uses embed git so you have to add it to the window path

Comment: If you found the answer, then better to put it as an answer to this question so it will be useful for others :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol) it says:

> Note: VS Code will leverage your machine's Git installation, so you
>   need to install Git first before you get these features. Make sure you
>   install at least version 2.0.0.

So there needs to be a Git on your system to get it working. Using the embedded Git from your Sourcetree installation will probably work, but might not be the cleanest solution. The Git in my Sourcetree installation (on a Mac) is about 3 years old (2.2.1). On a Mac there is also a Git preinstalled though (2.11.0), so here it works out of the box.

Answer (score 24):

Assuming you have git installed all you do is go to `View`->`Show Status Bar` (as seen below).  It will then show your current branch on the bottom of your current editor window.

[image: Menu Being Selected]

Comment: It might also be necessary to right-click the status and check 'Source Control'.

Comment: In 2022, the menus have changed.  Use View > Appearance > Status bar

Answer (score 14):

**For windows:**
The easiest thing would be to change your integrated terminal shell from Powershell to Git Bash. You can do that by going to File > Preferences > Setting and changing the integrated terminal shell, as illustrated below:

[image]

**For mac navigate to:**
Code> Preferences> settings> Search for 'terminal'

Comment: Good thought, this setting can also be changed from within the normal powershell terminal window.

Comment: Which vscode extension are you using to show the current branch @ttfreeman

Comment: @walexy it is not an extension. Git Bash is a linux look-alike terminal that comes with git installation. This is how you can add it to VS Code: https://blog.danielpadua.dev/posts/git-bash-with-vscode/

Comment: That being said, I have been using WSL2 for a few years now and no need to use git bash when you can get an actual linux terminal!

Comment: @ttfreeman Am referring to how ur teminal was showing ```(feature)```

Comment: @walexy I think by default Git Bash should show the branch name in the command prompt. If not, you can google to see why. But for Ubuntu in WSL you can add that by updating ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: @ttfreeman Am using ubuntu. What do i add to the ~/.bashrc file

Comment: @walexy please follow this link or search Google . There are many ways to do that: https://dev.to/sonyarianto/how-to-add-git-branch-name-to-shell-prompt-in-ubuntu-1gdj

Answer (score 6):

In year 2022

1. From top menu, select and check View > Appearance > **Status bar**
2. Status bar appears at bottom of VS Code Window
3. Branch displays in Status bar on left-side

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you're looking for display on the command-line [prompt] or in the VSCode UI.

There's this alternative view provided by the sidebar plugin that fits the bill when the `Source Control Repositories` option is checked (right-click on the topmost `Source Control` header): [image]

UI branch controls!
[image]

Comment: This was what I needed to restore my view of this after a crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you would also like to show the working branch in the Visual code Terminal Window, Try installing posh-git from chocolatey, you get all the git summarycolor codings and tab completion with the branch name in highlighted colors. If you are running  a Powershell version less than 6, make sure to set execution policies above Restricted.